# Parsing title from m4a or wav?

Tags: objective-c, ios, parsing, wav, m4a

How I can easily parse the title from a wav or m4a file on iOS(objective-c) ?

Thanks for the solutions.

Comment: Have you tried regular expression? The same question, what have you tried?

Comment: I try only this way, but it's only work for mp3.

Comment: CFDictionaryRef piDict = nil;
    UInt32 piDataSize = sizeof(piDict);
    
    err = AudioFileGetProperty(fileID, kAudioFilePropertyInfoDictionary, &piDataSize, &piDict);
    if(err != noErr) {
        NSLog(@"AudioFileGetProperty failed for property info dictionary");
    }
    
    NSDictionary* nsDict = (__bridge NSDictionary*)piDict;
    NSString *title = [nsDict objectForKey:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:kAFInfoDictionary_Title]];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSBundle* bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString* path = [bundle bundlePath];
NSURL * fileURL=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/silence.mp3", path]];
AudioFileTypeID fileTypeHint = kAudioFileMP3Type;
NSString *fileExtension = [[fileURL path] pathExtension];
if ([fileExtension isEqual:@"mp3"]||[fileExtension isEqual:@"m4a"])
{
    AudioFileID fileID  = nil;
    OSStatus err        = noErr;

    NSDictionary *piDict = nil;
    UInt32 piDataSize   = sizeof( piDict );
    err = AudioFileGetProperty( fileID, kAudioFilePropertyInfoDictionary, &piDataSize, &piDict );
    if( err != noErr ) {
        [piDict release];
        NSLog( @"AudioFileGetProperty failed for property info dictionary" );
    }

    NSString * Album = [piDict objectForKey: 
                        [NSString stringWithUTF8String: kAFInfoDictionary_Album]];
    NSString * Artist = [piDict objectForKey: 
                         [NSString stringWithUTF8String: kAFInfoDictionary_Artist]];
    NSString * Title = [piDict objectForKey: 
                        [NSString stringWithUTF8String: kAFInfoDictionary_Title]];
    NSLog(@"%@",Title);
    NSLog(@"%@",Artist);
    NSLog(@"%@",Album);

}
```